# Pandas dataframe first x columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with about 500 columns and that's why I am wondering if there is anyway that I could use `head()` function but want to see the first 50 columns for example.

Thanks

Answer (score 96, accepted):

I wasn't sure if you meant rows or columns.

If it's rows, then

```
df.head(50)
```

will do the trick.

If it's columns, then

```
df.iloc[:, : 50]
```

will work.

Of course, you can combine them.

---

You can see this stuff at [Indexing and Selecting Data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html).

Comment: This answer is outdated for the current version of python.

Comment: @conchoecia Yep, you're right, thanks. Updated.

Comment: @AmiTavory I think he meant something like df.iloc[:5, :50], then it is equivalent to having e.g., head(n=5) of the first 50 columns.